# AJAX jQuery CSS - animate div again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have online banking form which calls a ajax request. If something is wrong I'm showing a div with CSS classes. The CSS classes do animate the div.

So if I put the wrong pin for example it shakes my div. Code goes:

```
$("#div-error").css('display', 'inline-block', 'inline-block');
$("#div-error").html("<i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i> text here");
```

If I type another pin which is also wrong I want to shake the div again, but actually its just standing there.

How can I solve this?

I already tried to display>none the div and display>inline-block it again.

Comment: code and question does not seem to be matching.

Comment: remove the class that does the animation and re-add it.  Also your `.css` above is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pete mentioned you need to remove and re-add the css-class that will kickoff the CSS animation.

Short example here: https://jsfiddle.net/36484n3b/

```
$("#div-error").addClass("shake");
setTimeout(function(){ $("#div-error").removeClass("shake"); }, 1000);
```

Comment: arrgh. so logic. didn't think about it.